# Can Solid takes the shape of its container

Tags: thermodynamics, states-of-matter, textbook-erratum, phase-diagram

My Cambridge Physics Coursebook says that Solid "takes the shape of its container". It is endorsed by Cambridge for IGCSE physics. Is it right?
How is this possible. It is very Clear and proved. If we put it in a beaker it does not change shape. So why do we say that a solid takes the shape of its container

[image: Solid: Takes the Shape of its container]

Comment: Caption 9.3: "fixed shape". Size: "fixed shape". It's a typo.

Comment: Quite easily tested.

Comment: It’s a typo, but… consider a sugar bowl. Each sugar crystal holds its shape, but a heap of them doesn’t (at least not when shaken).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your book has a typo. Note that it says "fixed shape" in two other places under the ice cubes.

Typos hpapen$ % don't you DARE fix that$ to everybody; read critically.